# If we are able to contain the energy released by the center of atom or manipulate the amount of electron neutron and proton it contain,what'll happen?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, electrons, neutrons, protons

I mean, if we could actually manipulate the amount of electron proton and neutron an atom contains and can actually contain all the energy released by it, are we going to be able to shape shift? So, our body are made of proteins, every single cell. Proteins are made of elements. Elements are made of atoms which contains different amount of electron proton and neutron. So if we are able to manipulate them, can we shape shift into anything?

Comment: Manipulate how? And what exactly is shape shifting? (shifting "shape" doesn't really sound like something that require us to look at atoms types)

Comment: @Steeven  shape shifting, I am guessing you might know :), is probably Terminator 1, 2, 3.4.........stuff, robot into man idea

Comment: @CountTo10 Just wanted to be sure :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a picture that might interest you, taken with an Atomic Force Microscope.

[image]

These are actual atoms, that have been put into place by people operating a high powered microscope.

I don't know exactly how long it took to do this, but let's say it took 30 minutes. There are about 30 atoms there.

The problem is that your body has at least
 7,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 atoms, so it would take a long, long time to shift these atoms into new positions. Then we would have make sure the new shifted shape worked properly, with the atoms of blood vessels, heart, lungs all working correctly.

It is impossible, basically. It would be much, much easier to start from scratch than shape shift, in my opinion.

Comment: so they actually disrupted the nucleus of the atom and this is a picture of it?

Comment: No, sorry, when you look at this picture, you are seeing a computer generated image of the electric charge **around** the entire atom, not just the nucleus. It's not a direct picture, as nobody,  so far as I know, has seen, or will ever see, a bare atom, what we see here is the electric charge. But it's the best we can do right now. So, for the moment, nanotechnology, moving atoms or nuclei, on an individual basis, is still pretty much science fiction.  It's a slow process to move them one by one, we need a better way that they can self assemble, if that is ever possible.